# Should I write iterators for a class that is just a wrapper of a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

Should I write iterators for a class that is just a wrapper of a vector?

The only private member of my class called Record is a vector.

I want to be able to do this:

```
for (auto& elem : record) {
    // do something with elem
}
```

where record is of type Record. To do this I need to implement iterators
for the Record class. But, I can also do this:

```
for (auto& elem : record.elems) {
    // do something with elem
}
```

where record.elems is the vector I mentioned. But this way
I will need to make it public.

Another approach is:

```
for (auto& elem : record.getElems()) {
    // do something with elem
}
```

this way I get iteration, and the member stays private.
Probably this is the best way to go.

My main question is, why would I bother to implement iterators for the Record class
when it is just a wrapper for a vector? My colleague insists I implement iterators,
and he can't even explain me why, it is just stupid.

Comment: You just need to implement `being()` and `end()`, if I'm not mistaken. Returning the underlying vector iterators should work...

Comment: I'd also say it partly depends on what's inside those loops. If you can keep them inside the Record class and expose functions that operate on the whole set, it might be an alternative.

Comment: OK but my whole point is why bother at all? The vector and iteration mechanism is already there.

Comment: Might I ask why you need to wrap a std::vector in the first place? You can always use a typedef instead.

Comment: @user3111311, you tell us what's the point. You seem to be trying to solve a problem, but you asked us about the solution you had in mind instead.

Comment: Well I need to capture some functionality in the class, that is why.

Comment: Do you need to capture changes to the data inside the vector? Since changes can happen through the iterator, you need to implement your own iterators

Comment: @StoryTeller Well yeah, basically the problem is what a hell could the gain of that be? I am trying to decode my colleague, because obviously he can't give explanation. He keeps insisting I do iterators. But the class is just a wrapper for a vector what a hell! :)

Comment: @user1781290 I can just return references to the vector elements when I need to make changes, that is not a reason do implement iterators :)

Comment: My main question is why would you have class that has one member

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl this might make sense in some cases. At least you can add methods to the class, even if it has only one member

Comment: I think that part of the question is: how to implement those iterators correctly, in a way that doesn't break in subtle ways the implicit contract of C++ vector iterators (typedefs, const, exception safety, etc.). Last time I read an article about C++, it was very hard to implement a correct swap method (I'm not trolling, I like C++, but...).

Comment: @StoryTeller Hmm implementing `being()` is better left to gods IMHO. ;-)

Comment: @RedX, well, human philosophers can at least *try* and define it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implementing iterators will help the encapsulation of your class. If at any point in time, you decide to replace the backing vector with another data type, you might break dependencies.

Actually, you do not need to *implement* the iterator. You can `typedef` your iterators to be the vector iterators and create inline `begin()` and `end()` methods to return the vector's iterators.

**EDIT:** As requested a simple example:

```
template <class T>
class vectorWrapper
{
  typedef typename std::vector<T> backingType;
  backingType v;
public:
  typedef typename backingType::iterator iterator;
  typedef typename backingType::const_iterator const_iterator;
  iterator begin() { return v.begin(); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return v.begin(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const { return v.cbegin(); } // C++11
  iterator end() { return v.end(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return v.end(); }
  const_iterator cend() const { return v.cend(); } // C++11
};
```

If needed (or wanted) `reverse_iterator`s can be added the same way. Since the methods are likely to be inlined by the compiler, there is little to no overhead in using this.

Comment: We will never change the vector, it will remain vector always. The problem is that simple, there is absolutely no chance that that will change. So yeah, the vector will remain there for good.

Comment: Of course you can just return the whole vector or a reference to it. But it'll take only about 10 lines of code to be on the safe side. Your choice

Comment: So the point of dispute here is whether it should be possible to iterate over `Record` itself, or whether it should expose a vector to iterate over. Your colleague says the former, you say the latter. Since nobody here knows what the class is for, we can't make that call. Generally the difference is minor, but it's whether, from the POV of the outside user, a `Record` "is" a range of elements or merely "offers access to" a range of elements. Your organization probably has some concept of seniority to decide matters where colleagues cannot agree after all argument is exhausted.

Comment: @user1781290 Can you give more details on how to typedef the iterators and what exactly should the begin and end methods do?Maybe write a short example here, that will be useful for others in future?

Comment: @user3111311 Added a small example

Comment: @user1781290 Third form `cbegin()` you forgot a c. `return cbegin();`.

Comment: @RedX Changed it and Thank you. Actually it should even work without the 'c' but it is more understandable anyway with the 'c'

Answer (score 2):

If your class should look a range, you are best off to provide access to iterators via `begin()` and `end()` members. The key advantage is that objects of the class can be used consistent with other ranges: there isn't much doubt of how the class is meant to use and the effort is small: unless you don't expect your class to be used, you should make it as easy and obvious to use. Of course, if you don't expect you class to be used why bother writing it in the first place?

Whether these need to have a different type than those of the vector depends on whether you need to impose any constraints. If the class does 't impose constraints on the elements or on their order it is sufficient to pass on the iterators. Otherwise it may be necessary to create custom iterators.